# jPanelMenu not working properly in IE (all versions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, jpanelmenu

I'm using the jPanelMenu jQuery plugin on one of my websites. I noticed a problem in IE (all versions).

When the menu is triggered, it slides in as it's supposed to. After clicking a menu item, the page scrolls to the desired section and closes again. As the menu closes, the right side of the website gets an unwanted margin. When opening the menu again, it's half it's size and closes the gap of the content again.

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/huzLU/1/

And three screenshots showing the problem in IE:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKask.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItIBa.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/99s9S.jpg

Here's the code I'm using for the menu:

```
<script>
$(document).on('touchend',jP.panel,function(e){
e.preventDefault();
if ( jP.menuIsOpen() ) jP.closeMenu(jP.options.animated);
});

$(document).on('click',jP.panel,function(e){
e.preventDefault();
if ( jP.menuIsOpen() ) jP.closeMenu(jP.options.animated);
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var jPM = $.jPanelMenu({
closeOnContentClick: false
});
jPM.on();

$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

var target = this.hash,
$target = $(target);

$('html, body').stop().animate({
'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-50
}, 900, 'swing', function () {
window.location.hash = target;
});
setTimeout(function() {
jPM.close(true);
}, 900, 'swing');
});

});
</script>
```

Also; here's the link to the website: www.didson.nl

I hope someone can help me out, thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post your CSS, please?

Comment: @MelanciaUK the jsFiddle contains the `style.css` file as an external resource. It's ~550 lines so it might be better to inspect it from there rather than post it all here.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I could post the CSS, but as filoxo said; it's quite long and also included in the jsFiddle

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Try this new [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hige/huzLU/8/).
I fixed the setTimeout call to close. (Actually, you wouldn't need to set a timeout at all)

Regards

The issue is related to styles. It is setting the div with class ".jPanelMenu-panel" to "position: relative;" which, is causing some issues.

In this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hige/huzLU/6/) you can see how, by setting the position to absolute, fixes the issue. The transition looks awful, sure, but I let that up to you.

Your version's HTML:

```
<div class="jPanelMenu-panel" style="position: relative; left: 0px;">
```

The line I added:

```
    $(".jPanelMenu-panel").css('position', 'absolute');
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Could you be a little more specific, please?

Comment: Sorry, It's weird, since it was working for me, yesterday. I'll come back later with a better answer